# Reducing Halting Problem to Acceptor for TM

Tags: turing-machines, reductions, halting-problem

We have $A_{TM}=\{(M,w)|M$ is a TM, $w\in \Sigma^*_{TM},M$ accepts $w\}$

We intend to show that $HALT(M,w)\leq_T A_{TM}$ i.e. if we are given a machine for $A_{TM}$, we can decide whether $M$ halts on $w$ using it.

So, if $M$ accepts $w$, machine halts and we are done.

But if $A_{TM}$ says rejected how to know if $M$ halts?

Comment: Given machine M and input $w$, try to build an instance of $A_{TM}$ which will accept some input only when M halts. Note: machine for $A_{TM}$ and input are not necessarily the same as $M$ and $w$

Comment: @Eugene if I convert the reject state to accept state, the $A_{TM}$ will be constructed right? And then $A_{TM}$ solves the halting problem.